# jsPdf not convert Image from nextJs as expected

Tags: html, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using NextJS and  from next-image.
I wrap  by div and use fill property. It's working normal on Chrome but when i use jsPdf to download Pdf, it's broken.

Here is my config for download pdf:

```
  const downloadPdf = () => {
    const input = pdfRef.current;
    html2canvas(input, { scale: 5 }).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
      const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', 'a5', true);
      const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);

      // doc and image dimensions
      const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
      const imgWidth = imgProps.width;
      const imgHeight = imgProps.height;

      // calculating right scale to fit the page
      const scale = Math.max(pdfHeight / imgHeight, pdfWidth / imgWidth);
      const finalWidth = imgWidth * scale;
      const finalHeight = imgHeight * scale;
      const leftMargin = (pdfWidth - finalWidth) / 2;
      // add image with alias and compression of your choice
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', leftMargin, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight, 'alias', 'FAST');
      pdf.save('certificate.pdf');
    });
  };
```

- My code with Image

```
        <div ref={certificateRef} className={`${styles.certificate__background} ${!dataCertificate && styles.disable}`}>
          <Image
            id="backgroundCertificate"
            src="/images/certificate-active.svg"
            alt="TEK4_IMAGE"
            fill
            priority
            style={{ objectFit: 'contain' }}
          />
        </div>
```